# Backbone pass values to view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have `index.html` containing

```
<div id="content">
     <script type="text/template" id="App1">
         Name: <%=name%><br />
         Company: <%=company%>
     </script>
</div>
```

`script.js` contains

```
var App1 = Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize: function(){
         this.render();
     },
     render: function(){
         var obj = {name: 'John', company: 'ABC Corp'};
         var template1 = _.template($('#App1').html(), obj);
         this.$el.html(template1);
     }
});

var app1 = new App1({
    el: '#content'
});
```

However, I get error as company variable is undefined.

What is causing this?

Comment: Not sure this is the cause of the issue, but you have wrong names.. var app1 = ..., but new App1(..) there is no such variable App1. var template1 = ..., but this.$el.html(template); there is no such variable template.. Check out your code, I suspect you have lot's of similar stuff..

Comment: same error variable company is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working version:

```
var App1 = Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize: function(){

         this.render();

     },
     render: function(){
         var obj = {name: 'John', company: 'ABC Corp'};
         var template1 = _.template($('#App1').html());

         this.$el.html(template1(obj));

     }
});

var app1 = new App1({
    el: '#App1'
});
```

The error is how you define and use template. Check this out: http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: Yes. This is how I also use when need to pass some data to template.